# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl , when throwing BadRequestException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

I have a handler class in my springbootapp that performs some validation on incoming REST requests and throws BadRequestException back to the controller class.

But instead of controller catching the BadRequestException, it catches Exception and throws

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl

I spend some time looking around for solution but dont seem to find any.

Here is my validation code in handler

```
    private void validateSignUpRequest(String phone) {
    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(phone))
        throw new BadRequestException("Phone Number can't be empty");
}
```

Here is the controller

```
@PostMapping(path = "/users/sign-up")
public ResponseEntity<UserData> signUpUser(@RequestBody Users user) {
    UserData userData = null;
    HttpStatus httpStatus = null;
    boolean flag = false;
    try {
        userData = userHandler.fetchByPhone(user.getPhoneNumber());
        if (userData == null) {
            flag = userHandler.saveUser(user);
            httpStatus = HttpStatus.CREATED;
        } else {
            userData = UserData.failureResponse("User Already Exist");
            httpStatus = HttpStatus.CONFLICT;
        }
    }catch(BadRequestException e) {
        userData = UserData.failureResponse(e.getMessage());
        httpStatus = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        userData = UserData.failureResponse(e.getMessage());
        httpStatus = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(userData,httpStatus);
}
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-rest -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/RuntimeDelegateImpl.java is under jersey-common.

You are missing `jersey-common` https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
       <version>.....</version>
    </dependency>
```